# How to access class properties using .(variable_name) in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, properties

I have a class as follows -

```
public class Student
{
    string name {get; set;}
    int age {get; set;}
}
```

I can access properties by -

```
Student s = new Student();
var age = s.age;
```

But what if I want to access properties by doing something like this -

```
Student s = new Student();
string property = "age";
var value = s.property
```

And this should return age.
The property I want to access is decided at runtime.

Also, I would be interested in knowing the reverse assignment. That is, instead of -

```
s.age = 25;
```

Something like

```
string property = "age";
s.property = 35;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the reason for you to do that. But you can achieve that by using **Reflection**. It is very valuable for certain scenarios, not so valuable for others, in this case is not necessary.

```
        Student s = new Student();
        string property = "age";
        var age = s.GetType().GetProperty(property);
        age.SetValue(s,25);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is not exactly the use case. The question was formed only to get the solution. Quick question -
If I want to do the reverse assignment, that is, 
s.age = 25;
s.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().First(x=>x.Name== property) = 25; doesn't work. Do you know solution for this too?